# What is the term for feeling down because of bad weather?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I am looking for the word that refers to a state of tiredness or slight depression because of bad weather conditions. The opposite is also true, that is feeling well or well-disposed because of nice, sunny weather.

The only term I could come up with is [meteoropathic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoropathy), but it is present only in Wikipedia.

What is the the appropriate common term for the condition described above?

Comment: "Weather Affective Disorder"? http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/seasonal-affective-disorder/basics/definition/con-20021047

Comment: @Elian - thanks, but is there a common, colloquial way to refer to this disorder?

Comment: "Bad Weather Blues" ;-) https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22efforts+went+downhill%22&biw=1024&bih=672&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSl9KztMLMAhUrKMAKHUviAFwQ_AUIBygA&dpr=2#q=%22bad+weather+blues%22

Answer (score 2):

Consider *winter blues*: (emphasis mine)

> The first and most well known way in which weather affects mood is in what is known as 'seasonal affective disorder' – abbreviated rather appropriately to 'SAD'. This condition can also be known as 'winter depression', '**winter blues**' or 'seasonal depression' and basically it describes a condition in which the individual finds their mood so tied to the changing of the seasons that they in fact exhibit symptoms close to depression every winter.
>   [- Stanley C Loewen, Effects of Weather on Human Emotions](http://www.healthguidance.org/entry/15843/1/Effects-of-Weather-on-Human-Emotions.html)